# repeating a php code without coding multiple times

Tags: php, repeat

This is my code:

```php
if (preg_match('/^\/start (.*)/', $text, $match) or preg_match('/^\/get_(.*)/', $text, $match)) {
    $id = $match[1];
    if (isJoin($from_id)) {
        $fileData = mysqli_query($db, "SELECT * FROM `file` WHERE `id` = '{$id}'");
        $file = mysqli_fetch_assoc($fileData);
        if (mysqli_num_rows($fileData)) {
            if ($file['password']) {
                sendMessage($from_id, "please send pass :", "markdown", $btn_back, $message_id);
                mysqli_query($db, "UPDATE `user` SET `step` = 'password', `getFile` = '$id' WHERE `from_id` = '$from_id'");
            } else {
                $downloads = number_format($file['downloads']);
                $downloads++;
                $caption = urldecode($file['caption']);
                Ilyad("send{$file['type']}", [
                    'chat_id' => $from_id,
                    $file['type'] => $file['file_id'],
                    'caption' => " count : <code>{$downloads}</code>\n{$caption}\n Thanks",
                    'parse_mode' => "html",
                ]);
                Ilyad("send{$file['type']}", [
                    'chat_id' => $from_id,
                    $file['type'] => $file['file_id2'],
                    'caption' => " count : <code>{$downloads}</code>\n{$caption}\n Thanks",
                    'parse_mode' => "html",
                ]);
                mysqli_query($db, "UPDATE `file` SET `downloads` = `downloads`+1 WHERE `id` = '$id'");
                mysqli_query($db, "UPDATE `user` SET `step` = 'none', `downloads` = `downloads`+1 WHERE `from_id` = '$from_id'");
            }
        } else sendMessage($from_id, "hi welcome to bot", 'markdown', $btn_home, $message_id);
    } else {
        joinSend($from_id);
        mysqli_query($db, "UPDATE `user` SET `getFile` = '$id' WHERE `from_id` = '$from_id'");
    }
}
```

so what i want to do is repeat this code like 24 times but each time the number at the end of **file_id** changes like file_id1, file_id2, file_id3, ..., file_id24.

and the values for file_id1, ... and others are stored on my SQL database.

Now if you see there is two codes repeating and the only change is the number at the end of **file_id** so i want to make it 24 codes but instead of just repeating it I want to do it with one code.

and another thing I said 1 to 24 can i also do something so it reads the last number from a database value to like loop from 1 to x and x is the number i entered in database.

sorry i'm new to programming.

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.for.php

Comment: Your code and question are incomplete. Please share all relevant parts.

Comment: Are you missing a function name before this: `("send{$file['type']}", [...`? That should throw a syntax error.

Comment: On first glance I'd suggest to create a _function_ and have the number as a parameter. But then running SQL in a loop is always a bad thing, perhaps you're also looking for an array: https://php.net/array https://php.net/function - loops have been suggested already.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson yea i'll fix that now.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson: I stand corrected.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is wrap that code in a for loop that increments 1..N. Then in the body of the loop, append / interpolate the loop increment variable where you need it.

```
for ($i = 1; $i <= 24; $i++) {
    // ...
    ("send{$file['type']}", [
                'chat_id' => $from_id,
                $file['type'] => $file["file_id$i"],
                'caption' => " Count : <code>{$downloads}</code>\n{$caption}\n Thanks",
                'parse_mode' => "html",
            ]);
}
```

Comment: I tried your code, but it didn't work.

Comment: `for (var $i = 1;` should be `for ($i = 1;`.

Comment: @IlyadGreyrat "_it didn't work_" does not really help anyone. Try to post a more specific problem description and/or the complete error message you get